# Filter for questions for review

Tags: support, review

I received the requests for reviewing the questions.

Among them there are questions related to machine learning which I have not any knowledge. Is there any way (for example, modify my profile) such that the questions with machine learning tag will not come to my queue of questions?

Answer (score 8):

While you can filter by tag:

[image: filter link at top of Close Review screen]

Note that you can do this within queues for some tag-reasons but not others (I unchecked "off-topic" here since you don't need to know as much about a topic to see a post is off topic for our site).

In other places in StackExchange (searches, watched-vs-ignored tags), tag-filtering allows you to remove tags (using -[tagname]):

---

[image: using "-" in front of tag to filter it out]

---

.... but - for reasons I cannot fathom - it turns out that this doesn't work for reviews (!)

[image: Showing that the "-" gets stripped]

This makes the tag filter of only marginal value for your needs; we would need to take it up in the network meta -- meta.stackexchange.com. Either you or I could do it, but it's probably best if you take it up -- do search first for duplicates however.

Comment: I am stuck in the first step. How to come to the page with "Review   Close Votes    filter"

Comment: It should be right at the top when you review a post. If you look at the Close votes queue, then as soon as you look at the first item in the queue it should say "Review Close Votes", and so forth for any other queue.

Comment: Thank you, I found it finally. "-" before [machine-learning] means excluding [machine-learning]?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: My god, after I added -[machine-learning], I got 4 review requests, all of them have machine-learning tags. It seems the effect is opposite to what I expected.

Comment: Odd. Hang on, let me double check. It may be a while.

Comment: after I typing in -[machine-learning], and click "okay" button, later I check the filter, it is machine-learning, -[] disappeared.

Comment: Yes, I was just constructing the appropriate image to show that's what actually happens. This is not consistent with how tags work anywhere else.

Comment: My apologies for not carrying through to actually using the filter that way (I was trying to avoid actually filtering tags in my own account because I'm a moderator, but I should have actually tried a few to see that it was consistent with tag behavior elsewhere in the interface).